# Order of Bean Creation WebMvcConfigurerAdapter Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have convert xml to Java Class with the following code in Spring MVC. Can anyone tell me how to set order of bean creation. When i run the following code. JDBCTemplate bean create before DataSource Bean and give exception because Datasource is null.

```
package com.outbottle.config;  

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;  
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;  
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.outbottle")
@EnableWebMvc   
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
{  
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Bean  
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {  
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");  
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
        return resolver;  
    } 

    @Bean  
    public org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource setDataSource() 
    {  
        dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUsername("muhiuddin");
        dataSource.setPassword("muhiuddin");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.0.10:1521:db10g");
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean  
    public JdbcTemplate setJdbcTemplate() 
    {  
        jdbcTemplate= new JdbcTemplate();
        // setDataSource(); // if I call this function then every thing is OK.
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }      

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR: Never use instance variables

Your code should be:

```
@Bean  
public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() 
{  
    final DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUsername("muhiuddin");
    dataSource.setPassword("muhiuddin");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.0.10:1521:db10g");
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
    dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean  
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(final javax.sql.DataSource dataSource) 
{  
    final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate= new JdbcTemplate();
    // setDataSource(); // if I call this function then every thing is OK.
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

This way Spring *knows* that to create a `JdbcTemplate` bean it needs a `DataSource` bean; so it will decide on the order correctly.

You have bypassed Spring by using instance variables, which Spring cannot determine the creation time of.

---

Two other things:

1. An `@Bean` method's name sets the bean name, do you really want a `DataSource` bean called `setDataSource`?
2. Your beans should return the `interface` or `abstract class` rather than the specific type, this is to encourage autowiring by `interface`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you explain what mean "TL;DR: Never use instance variables". thanks in advance.

Comment: [TL:DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read); Never use instance variables. @MUHIUDDIN

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@DependsOn` Annotation to set an order for bean creation

Something like that:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("setDataSource")  
public JdbcTemplate setJdbcTemplate() 
{  
    jdbcTemplate= new JdbcTemplate();
    // setDataSource(); // if I call this function then every thing is OK.
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

But you can also do call the method itself:

```
@Bean  
public org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource getDataSource() 
{  
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUsername("muhiuddin");
    dataSource.setPassword("muhiuddin");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.0.10:1521:db10g");
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
    dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean  
public JdbcTemplate setJdbcTemplate() 
{  
    jdbcTemplate= new JdbcTemplate();
    // setDataSource(); // if I call this function then every thing is OK.
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a hack to get around abuse of `@Configuration`. See my answer.