# Cannot create jdbcTemplate bean correctly - Spring In Action

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datasource, spring-jdbc

I'm reading "Spring In Action" recently and I got a strange problem in chapter 10. It confuse me a whole day.

Here's my `WebConfig.java`(DispatcherServlet config)

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@ComponentScan(value = "io.lilpig.springlearn.springlearn02.web")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean("dataSource")
    @Profile("dev")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        System.out.println("CREATING DATASOURCE H2");
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:test-data.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource dataSource(
            @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url,
            @Value("${jdbc.username}") String username,
            @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password,
            @Value("${jdbc.driverClass}") String driverClass,
            @Value("${jdbc.initialSize}") Integer initialSize,
            @Value("${jdbc.maxPoolSize}") Integer maxPoolSize,
            @Value("${jdbc.minPoolSize}") Integer minPoolSize,
            @Value("${jdbc.maxIdleTime}") Integer maxIdleTime
    ) throws PropertyVetoException {
        System.out.println("CREATING DATASOURCE c3p0");
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDriverClass(driverClass);
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(initialSize);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(minPoolSize);
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(maxIdleTime);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    @DependsOn("dataSource")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("CREATING jdbcTemplate");
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    // other beans......
}
```

And here is my RepositoryCode

```java
@Repository
@Primary
@DependsOn("jdbcTemplate")
public class JdbcSpitterRepository implements SpitterRepository{

    JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;
    BeanPropertyRowMapper<Spitter> mapper;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcSpitterRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
        this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations;
        this.mapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Spitter>(Spitter.class);
    }
    // some method in repository
}
```

The problem I got is sometimes the application can run correctly (in both dev profile and prod profile), but sometimes it can't.

When the application start fails, dataSource wasn't created by Spring. It seems like jdbcTemplate was creating before dataSource. So I added the `@DependsOn` annotation, but the error still happens occasionally.

And I set the active profile by these code in my Initializer class extends from AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer:

```java
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "prod");
}
```

Here is the log when I got an error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in io.lilpig.springlearn.springlearn02.config.WebConfig: 'jdbcTemplate' depends on missing bean 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' available
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
根本原因。

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' available
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of Bean Creation WebMvcConfigurerAdapter Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033101/order-of-bean-creation-webmvcconfigureradapter-spring)

Comment: First set the parameter and then call `super.onStartup`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your answer. But it didn't work in my application.

Comment: What didn't work? Your initial snippet showed you set the property **after** the initialization of everything, depending on the timing that might be too late. You need to set the properties before any initialization. Also, again, depending on timing the `ServletContext` might not even be considered for resolution (yet).

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok, Thank you for your time. As you say, it seems Spring didn't receive the parameter I set before the application was started. I made a lot of attempts for example call `setInitParameter` after `super.onStartup`, override `createRootApplicationContext` and call `addActiveProfile` via `Environment` object, set compile argument `-Dspring.profiles.active` ... But none of them solved the problem. I noticed when I deleted the code contains `@Value` annotation, It works!And when I put them in my code again,It still work! Although I don't know what's the problem is,thank you for your help!